# Can't install android-sdk using homebrew

Tags: android, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am trying to install `android-sdk` using `homebrew` using the following command :

```
brew cask install android-sdk
```

Everything goes fine until:

```
LinuxPluss-Mac:~ linuxplus$   brew cask reinstall android-sdk
==> Caveats
We will install android-sdk-tools, platform-tools, and build-tools for you.
You can control android sdk packages via the sdkmanager command.
You may want to add to your profile:
  'export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk'

This operation may take up to 10 minutes depending on your internet connection.
Please, be patient.

==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zi
Already downloaded: /Users/linuxplus/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/android-sdk--25.2.3.zip
==> Verifying checksum for Cask android-sdk
Error: Operation not permitted - /usr/local/share/android-sdk
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1439:in `unlink'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1439:in `block in remove_file'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1444:in `platform_support'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1438:in `remove_file'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:785:in `remove_file'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:563:in `block in rm'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:562:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:562:in `rm'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask_loader.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in load'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/artifact/abstract_flight_block.rb:35:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/artifact/abstract_flight_block.rb:35:in `block in abstract_phase'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb:232:in `each_key'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb:232:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/artifact/abstract_flight_block.rb:34:in `abstract_phase'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/artifact/abstract_flight_block.rb:28:in `uninstall_phase'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/installer.rb:330:in `block in uninstall_artifacts'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/installer.rb:327:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/installer.rb:327:in `uninstall_artifacts'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/installer.rb:312:in `uninstall'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/reinstall.rb:27:in `block in install_casks'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/reinstall.rb:6:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/reinstall.rb:6:in `install_casks'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/install.rb:10:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:115:in `run_command'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:158:in `process'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/cask.rb:8:in `cask'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:91:in `<main>'
```

Why am i getting this permission issue?

Comment: Did you try reporting a homebrew bug like the message says?

Answer (score 1):

The unlink operation was not permitted. You need to run the command as sudo or give your current user the permissions over that directory.

```
sudo brew cask reinstall android-sdk
```

or

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```